# Does ARMA-EGARCH require a stationary time series?

Tags: time-series, arima, stationarity, garch

For modelling the conditional variance of a real exchange rate by an ARMA-EGARCH model, should the real exchange rate series be stationary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to apply an ARMA model for the conditional mean of a process, the process should be stationary. Otherwise an ARMA model will not be appropriate. Real exchange rates might generally be integrated processes, so it might make more sense to apply an ARIMA-EGARCH model with the order of integration equal to 1 in the ARIMA model. You could test for the oder of integration using unit-root and stationarity tests (e.g. augmented Dickey-Fuller, KPSS and other). You should also watch out for changes in the unconditional mean and unconditional variance over time (structural breaks or gradual changes) which could render pure ARIMA-EGARCH models inappropriate.

Comment: thanks for ur answer I am using eviews 9 for my estimations. And ı am selecting my arma model by add inns auto arma selection. After choosing arma model I am applying arch models.  dlnkur c ar(1) ar(2) ma(1) and than different arch models with different p and q orders. After estimation I checked lowest aıc and sc values for best arch model.

Comment: Are you doing the ARIMA-EGARCH estimation in one step or sequentially (ARIMA first, then EGARCH)? You should do that in one step.

Comment: after selected arma model doing it in one step  in eviews 9 mean equation part dlnkur c ar(1) ar(2) ma(1) and at the same window variance and distribution specification part for egarch model

Comment: @ylmz, Have I answered the question, or is there something else you need to know?

Comment: I need to conditional variance of  real exchange rates so ı got ur answer my exchaange rate should be stationary for estimating by arh models. So  ı will estimate conditional variance of real exchange from first difference of reel exchange rate series

Comment: @ylmz, fine, I just wondered since the answer was neither accepted nor upvoted.

Comment: I  am new hear and actually ı dont know how to vote it